# How to report if a control exists more than once in a web page?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

Can anybody say that if a control for example a button is available more than once, we have to say that the button is available more than once.

Answer (score 1):

Look at below Code sample, which might help:

```cs
WinButton button = new WinButton(parent);
button.SearchProperties[WinButton.PropertyNames.Name] = propertyValue;
int buttonCount = button.FindMatchingControls().Count();
if(buttonCount > 1)
   //then it means that button is available more than once.
```